# MVC Testing in VS 2010 vs VS 11

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

Over the last 2 months, I've been trying to learn the new MVC framework.  After getting my head around all the object oriented concepts, I created a test site using MVC3, EF4 w/ DbContext, and ASP.Net Membership provider.  All was going pretty well.  Then, I decided to dive in and learn testing, starting with Unit Testing.

After 2 weeks of banging my head against my keyboard, I now feel as frustrated as can be.  I've gone through tons of video tutorials (TekPub, Plural-sight), online tutorials (ASP.Net, Microsoft, etc..etc..) and plenty of StackOverflow questions/answers.  I now *sort-of* (ha!) understand Loose Coupling, Dependency Injection, Respositories, Interfaces, Stubs, Mocks (yes, I read the Fowler article many times), Shims, lambdas, refactoring...the list goes on and on (...and on.).  I've looked at Ninject, Structuremap, Moq, TypeMock, JustMock, nUnit, xUnit, etc...

So I know there are a bunch of ways to skin this cat.  Now I see that VS11/MVC4 is coming out and they have this thing called Fakes which seem to be a good option for static methods like the Membership stuff.

My question:

I want to test my MVC EF4/DbContext/Membership application.  Most of my pages require an authenticated user [Authorize] and thats before I even get to the actual method to be tested.

If you were just starting out (like me), what is the simplest and easiest route to testing my CRUD application?  I don't necessarily like having a DI framework running on the production side (just another thing that might go wrong) and I find the fracking things are confusing as all get out.

I could upgrade to VS11/MVC4 and try the Fakes approach.  Appears to be slightly simpler but still seems like I need all the Respository/Interfaces for EF stuff.

Or would you just chuck it and use an Integration Test tool like Selenium (which is what I had to use before with Forms based development)?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Sorry if this is a lousy question but I'm hoping for a ray of light here...

Answer (score 0):

For all versions of mvc or programs its almost same way of testing.

You sould have most of your logic based on interfaces.
this will allow you to separate concerns and unit test anything you need also this will give you posiibility to fake (create fake implementations) or mock (create class on runtime that will represent logic you want, using Mock, or Rhino Mock) the logic.

You can read more about basic unit testing here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942838.aspx

also i would recomend you have a look on book where Steven Sanderson has example application including unit testing of most parts.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-ebook/dp/B005PZ07US

Here you have introduction to MOQ
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/182847/An-Introduction-to-MOQ

You have alternative such as rhino mock:

http://ayende.com/blog

and some examples:
http://daysincode.blogspot.com/2012/06/examples-of-mocking-with-rhino-moq.html

Of course everything here leads to : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ekstremalna-przerobka-asp-net--czesc6-podzial-obowiazkow.aspx